# PDO prepare stops script without giving error

Tags: php, pdo

I looked all over for solutions but couldn't find any. I checked my code and can't seem to find   any errors with it.

```
try
{
    $handle = new PDO("mysql:dbname=" . DATABASE . ";host=" . SERVER, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
    $handle->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $handle->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
}
catch (Exception $e)
{
    trigger_error($e->getMessage(), E_USER_ERROR);
    exit;
}
$sendData = $handle->prepare("INSERT INTO 'posts' (body, user, comments, likes, username, datetime) VALUES(:body, :userid, 'none', 'none', :username, :datetime)");
$sendData->bindParam(':body',$this->body);
$sendData->bindParam(':userid',$this->userID);
$sendData->bindParam(':username',$this->username);
$sendData->bindParam(':datetime',$this->datetime);
$sendData->execute();
```

I determined that the code stops before it even reaches the "bindParam" part. It stops right after the prepare call.

EDIT: As it turns out the error was in the $handle part. I declared handle elsewhere and didn't use "global" to add it inside this function. I feel so stupid.

Comment: [`error_reporting(E_ALL);`](http://php.net/error_reporting)

Comment: `"INSERT INTO 'posts'` -> why did you quote the table name using single quotes instead of using tilde (`) character?

Comment: if you going to catch the error on the connection you might as well catch for the whole code . and if anything catch PDOException

Comment: I tried using tilde, still didn't work

Comment: it's backtick, not tilde `~`. You should surround your table name with the backtick (`). Or you could just remove the quotes/ticks altogether.

Comment: Yeah I tried the backtick. Didn't work

Comment: then remove the single quotes.

Comment: Whe are you explicitly asking for exceptions, and then not capturing the exceptions your prepare might throw?

Comment: Yes, as wrikken and meda hinted at, move the entire prepare/bind/execute into your try statement. If those parts have errors, the try/catch will catch them too.

Comment: It doesn't throw any errors, I checked

Comment: check again...maybe explicitly set `error_reporting(E_ALL)` and `ini_set('display_errors',1)`. You could also check your error log. Even when an error doesn't show, it gets written to log.

Comment: If your function requires ```$handle``` then you should add that as a parameter to the function instead of declaring it as a global variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
try {
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=DATEBASE;charset=utf8', 'USER', 'PASSWORD');
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, FALSE);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

} 
catch(PDOException $ex) {
echo "something";
die();
}

$body = $_POST['body'];
$userID = $_POST['userID'];
$username = $_POST['username'];
$datetime = $_POST['datetime'];
$none = "none";
$sendData = $sb->prepare("INSERT INTO `posts` (body, user, comments, likes, username, datetime) VALUES(:body, :userid, :none, :none, :username, :datetime)");
$sendData->bindValue(':body', $body);
$sendData->bindValue(':none', $none);
$sendData->bindValue(':userid', $userID);
$sendData->bindValue(':username', $username);
$sendData->bidnValue(':datetime', $datetime);
$sendData->execute();
```

**Edited:**

```
`posts` instead 'posts'
```

Comment: didn't work. I used echo statements to determine that the code stops after the prepare call.

Comment: even after the edits it still didn't work and the prepare is not throwing any errors